# Continuing the list with checkboxes

Tags: org-mode

Suppose that the cursor is currently after the word "bread" at the end of this piece:

```
* TODO Week1 [/]
SCHEDULED: <2015-08-09 Sun>
- [ ] Buy bread
```

When I press `Alt-Enter`, it adds a list item, but not a checkbox. Can I modify this behavior, so that a list that starts with a checkbox would continue with checkboxes as well?

Comment: Note that `M-S-Enter` will add a list item with a checkbox. Or it will add a checkbox to the current list item. Also adds headline with TODO keyword.

Comment: For me it always adds a headline with TODO. How do I cause it to add a list item with a checkbox?

Comment: `C-S-Enter` adds headlines, but `M-S-Enter` adds list items or headlines depending on context. Please check the variable `org-list-automatic-rules`.

Comment: You are right! I got confused between M and C! Thank you!